# OSError: cannot load library 'gobject-2.0': error 0x7e

Tags: python, django, windows, lib, weasyprint

I installed the package **weasyprint** according to the instructions [Installing weasyprint](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#windows) (Django project).
My system: win 10. I have installed **gtk3** and it is present in my **PATH**
[image: PAYH gtk3]

```
import weasyprint
...
@staff_member_required
def order_admin_pdf(request, order_id):
    # Получаем заказ по ID:
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
    # Передаем объект в функцию render_to через генерацию шаблона pdf.html HTML в виде строки:
    html = render_to_string('shop/orders/order_admin_pdf.html',
                            {'order': order})
    # Создаем объект овтета с типом содержимого application/pdf и заголовком Content-Disposition:
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=order_{}.pdf"'.format(order.id)
    # Вызов метода weasyprint для получения PDF документа:
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response,
                                           stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(
                                               settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'css/pdf.css')])
    return response
```

> OSError: cannot load library 'gobject-2.0': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'gobject-2.0'

Comment: https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/971

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starting from [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#bpo-36085-whatsnew) DLL dependencies for extension modules and DLLs loaded with `ctypes` on Windows are now resolved more securely. Only the system paths, the directory containing the DLL or PYD file, and directories added with `add_dll_directory()` are searched for load-time dependencies. *Specifically, PATH and the current working directory are no longer used*, and modifications to these will no longer have any effect on normal DLL resolution.

If you followed the installation guide from the [official documentation](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/first_steps.html#windows) then  the following example works.

```
import os

os.add_dll_directory(r"C:\Program Files\GTK3-Runtime Win64\bin")

from weasyprint import HTML

HTML('https://weasyprint.org/').write_pdf('weasyprint-website.pdf')
```

In essence you need to call `add_dll_directory()` before interacting with WeasyPrint.

Comment: The question was asked a long time ago and since then a lot has changed in my understanding) This answer is more suitable for solving this issue.

Comment: Thanks. I was facing similar issue

Comment: Same issues, I wish there was a way to have the DLLs in a sub dir of my project and only use those I need without a full GTK3 install. I know this is impossible but makes the distribution of the program difficult.

Comment: For the search engines: Using `os.add_dll_directory()` solved the following frequently reported error when importing `rpy2`: cannot load library '.../R.dll'  error 0x7e

Answer (score 8):

For MacOS this helped. Bascially you have to create few links.

> sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/glib/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
> /usr/local/lib/gobject-2.0 
>  sudo ln -s
> /opt/homebrew/opt/pango/lib/libpango-1.0.dylib
> /usr/local/lib/pango-1.0 
>  sudo ln -s
> /opt/homebrew/opt/harfbuzz/lib/libharfbuzz.dylib
> /usr/local/lib/harfbuzz 
>  sudo ln -s
> /opt/homebrew/opt/fontconfig/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib
> /usr/local/lib/fontconfig-1 
>  sudo ln -s
> /opt/homebrew/opt/pango/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.dylib
> /usr/local/lib/pangoft2-1.0

https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/1556#issuecomment-1097977671

Comment: Worked for me as well on MacOS.

Answer (score 5):

I got desperate and decided to install the library gtk2 `C:\Program Files (x86)\GTK2\lib\` and specify the first in the PATH list. It worked... But my OS - win 10 x64. Why the library GTK3 refused to work, I do not know.

Answer (score 3):

Solution that worked for me:

1. Following `weasyprint` [usage on Windows](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/first_steps.html#windows), download and install GTK.
2. Add GTK at start of python (*in this case `python manage.py runserver`*):

```py
# insert the GTK3 Runtime folder at the beginning. Can be bin or lib, depending on path you choose while installing.
GTK_FOLDER = r'C:\Program Files\GTK3-Runtime Win64\bin'
os.environ['PATH'] = GTK_FOLDER + os.pathsep + os.environ.get('PATH', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

For me this was about env variables not set correctly.

I had to add [GTK3](https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer) as a System env variable in Windows for my project to work (Windows 10).

Answer (score 0):

I made a django website for windows 10 with the weasyprint library. Also installed GTK+ for Windows Runtime Environment (version 3). The same errors were thrown.

I tried to swap paths in path, updated windows to 11, but it didn't help.
Then i pasted 'sitecustomize.py' like **Tontyna** https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/971#issuecomment-544195744 to the virtual environment folder '/Lib/site-packages',

another error occurred: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file.

It turned out that the 'C:\Users<User>\anaconda3\fontconfig.dll' library is being loaded.

In the file 'sitecustomize.py' I changed the line:
`os.environ['PATH'] = GTK_FOLDER + os.pathsep + os.environ.get('PATH', '')` 
to the line:
`os.environ['PATH'] = GTK_FOLDER`
and it WORKS

Answer (score 0):

I work on Windows 10 and had a similar issue. My problem got sorted after installing the latest GTK from https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases.